# Not able to set cookie for node and react using set-cookiee header

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, cookies

I am using node.js as backend and react for front-end. I am using express-session for session management. This is my signup function which is called from react on button click. It basically calls the node backend api using fetch.

```
signup = ()=>{
        if(this.state.tnc){
            fetch(config.BASE_URL+"/api/signup",{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                },
                body:JSON.stringify(this.state)
            })
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(res=>{console.log(document.cookie);console.log(res)})
        }
        else{
            window.alert('Please Accept the Terms and Conditions.')
        }
    }
```

This is how i have initialized my session in backend

```
router.use(session({
    secret:'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie:{
        httpOnly:true,
        maxAge : 3600000,
        sameSite : true
    },
    name:'_demo'
}))
```

This is the signup function in backend which is call on signup api call

```
signup : (req, res)=>{
        const sess = req.session
        SignUp.findOne({
            where:{phoneNumber:req.body.phoneCode+req.body.phoneNumber}
        }).then(result=>{
            if(result){
                res.send({status:'Success',data:'User Exists'})
            }
            else{
                const user = SignUp.build({
                    fullName:req.body.fullName,
                    email:req.body.email,
                    phoneNumber:req.body.phoneCode+req.body.phoneNumber,
                    aadharNumber:req.body.aadharNumber,
                    city:req.body.city,
                    state:req.body.state,
                    zipCode:req.body.zipCode,
                    country:req.body.country
                });
                user.save().then(result=>{
                    sess.userId = result.getDataValue('id')
                    res.send({status:'Success',data:result.getDataValue('id')})
                })
            }
        })
```

I am getting set cookiee header but it is not getting set in browser.
[image]

Comment: You have session id which has been sent to the browser as `_demo` cookie. What else you're expecting to get in the browser?

Comment: i am getting it in header but the when i see in dev tools in cookiee section i dont see the cookie being set. Also when i print document.cookie, it is not printed.

Comment: Change value of `httpOnly` to `false`. Otherwise browser is not giving you access to the cookie from JS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer it was because i was not setting proper cors policies.
After adding this to node using middleware

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

and setting credentials: 'include' in fetch api in the front-end did the work for me.

```
 fetch(config.BASE_URL+"/api/signup",{
                method:'POST',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                },
                body:JSON.stringify(this.state)
            })
```